# How can I pass return code from custom exe (does some check and gives error pop) that runs before .prq is run to main MSI

Tags: windows-installer, custom-action

How can I pass a return code from a custom executable (does some checking and gives an error popup) that runs before .PRQ is run to main MSI?  I need to do this so that the install quits after the pop up.

Answer (score 0):

Details depend on whatever tool you're using to build the MSI, but your custom action executable can just return a non-zero exit code. In WiX you'd use return="check" in the custom action element, as an example.

Comment: I am using Installshield for building MSI. I am running executable as .prq not CA, Because executable does some system check and gives the Message out on screen. This executable needs to run before another .prq-2 is run. I am trying to understand if I can run this executable as part of CA. If possible, I can get the return code and Fail the install deliberately. Although, Not aware of the method on how to run this using CA Before prq-2 is run.